# How to translate an Ethereum ENR address to an ENODE address?

Tags: node-discovery, enode

We want to translate a database of Ethereum Node Record (ENR) addresses to their ENODE counterparts.

How to convert an ENR address to an ENODE address?

Answer (score 1):

One can use enr-cli (https://github.com/AgeManning/enr-cli/)

```
$ enr-cli read "enr:-Je4QEeZoiY8OrUxlckLuU8leuuSfnrveD8PdUnCvHavJJzcGQn7nKikWNV_ZxbRtPt6si-tQNwT_aIYpksq3O2Hzblbg2V0aMfGhPCv0OOAgmlkgnY0gmlwhIe10fKJc2VjcDI1NmsxoQNGM7sxj2Wuen_j9kqzHEmjqSxct1UxxbA9kwl7ha7NRIN0Y3CCdl-DdWRwgnZf"
ENR Read:
Sequence No:91
NodeId: 009eef756b05e36100f55bc3a7b88031daeb83a3ebb66c4ccef0677ec477df3e
EnodeId: enode://009eef756b05e36100f55bc3a7b88031daeb83a3ebb66c4ccef0677ec477df3e:135.181.209.242:30303?discport=30303
Libp2p PeerId: 16Uiu2HAmHP2e815N2Qik2ffbdsapJCLRY3uUobuLJVNoGJEZs7b9
IP:135.181.209.242
TCP Port:30303
UDP Port:30303
Known multiaddrs:
/ip4/135.181.209.242/udp/30303
/ip4/135.181.209.242/tcp/30303
```